# how to transform data frame using pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame like :

```
   ID   id2       Materials
0  12   23       Plastic
1  12   54       Metal
2  12   63       NaN
3  13   75       NaN
4  13   24       Metal
```

What i want is to have only line per ID without losing informations about ID2 and materials.i thinki pivot function might work but honestly don't have an idea how to structure it. any idea of an output is :

```
   ID          Plastic   metal  
0  12           23        54
1  13           Nan        24
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `df.pivot('ID', 'id2', 'Materials')`?

Comment: Ijust edited my question

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After you edited your question, what you're looking for is to `reshape` your dataframe.
For what I understand you want to `pivot_table`. Meaning you'll change what you consider as a column, a value and an index. 
Try this:

```
df_pivoted = df.pivot_table(index="ID", columns="Materials", values="id2", \
                            dropna=True, fill_value=-1)
```

`dropNA` and `fill_value` to keep `int` otherwise it will convert values to `float`

Then you can `reset_index` to have ID as a columns:

```
df_pivoted.reset_index()
```

output:

```
Materials   ID  Glass   Metal   NaN     Plastic
        0   12     -1      54    63          23
        1   13     24      -1    -1          75
```

Comment: I'll use the dataframe as in input in a merge based on the ID , that's why i wanted a single line by ID, will i have problem with the join ?

Comment: I edited my answer based on what you have changed in your question, check it !

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output, you do want to `pivot` the datagram, with the `ID` column as the index, and forming a new column for each of the `Materials`. It also looks like you want to first drop the observations with a missing value (`NaN`) in `Materials`.

Putting those two steps together, the transformation is:

```py
df.dropna(subset=['Materials']) \
  .pivot(index='ID', columns='Materials')
```

With the output:

```py
            id2        
Materials Metal Plastic
ID                     
12         54.0    23.0
13         24.0     NaN
```

To format the dataframe as you desire, you have to take a few more steps:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['ID', 'Metal', 'Plastic']
```

The formatted dataframe is now:

```py
   ID  Metal  Plastic
0  12   54.0     23.0
1  13   24.0      NaN
```